# Conversão de SQL para LINQ C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, linq-to-sql

como faço para converter a última linha deste SQL para o LINQ?

```
SELECT* FROM
                 ACOMPANHAMENTO A,
                 PRESOS_ACOMPANHAMENTO PA, 
                 PRESOSS P
             WHERE
                 P.ID_PRESOS = 300 AND
                 PA.ID_PRESOS = P.ID_PRESOS AND
                 A.ID_Acomp = PA.ID_Acomp AND
                 A.ID_Area_Acomp = 15 AND
                 A.ID_Sit_Acomp IN (SELECT SA.ID_Sit_Acomp FROM SITUACAO_ACOMPANHAMENTO SA WHERE SA.ST_Sit_Acomp = 'A')
```

O código abaixo apresenta a minha tentativa de conversão do código SQL para LINQ.

```
var resultado = (from a in contexto.ACOMPANHAMENTOes
                         from pa in contexto.PRESO_ACOMPANHAMENTO
                         from p in contexto.PRESOS
                         where p.ID_Preso == 300 &&
                                  pa.ID_Preso == p.ID_Preso &&
                                  a.ID_Acomp == pa.ID_Acomp &&
                                  a.ID_Area_Acomp == 15 && 
                                  a.ID_Sit_Acomp.ToString().Contains(from sa in contexto.SITUACAO_ACOMPANHAMENTO where sa.ST_Sit_Acomp == "A" select sa.ID_Sit_Acomp)
                         select a).ToList();
```

Comment: Uma dúvida, o seu Presos é de prisão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conversão pode ficar da seguinte forma:

```
var sitAcomp = (from a in SITUACAO_ACOMPANHAMENTO 
                where a.ST_Sit_Acomp == 'A'
                select a).ToList();

var resultado = (from a in contexto.ACOMPANHAMENTOes
                 from pa in contexto.PRESO_ACOMPANHAMENTO
                 from p in contexto.PRESOS
                 where p.ID_Preso == 300 &&
                       pa.ID_Preso == p.ID_Preso &&
                       a.ID_Acomp == pa.ID_Acomp &&
                       a.ID_Area_Acomp == 15 &&
                           (from sa in sitAcomp
                            select sa.ID_Sit_Acomp)
                            .Contains(a.ID_Sit_Acomp)
                 select a).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Outra maneira seria

```
var resultado = (from a in contexto.ACOMPANHAMENTOes
                 from pa in contexto.PRESO_ACOMPANHAMENTO
                 from p in contexto.PRESOS
                 where p.ID_Preso == 300 &&
                       pa.ID_Preso == p.ID_Preso &&
                       a.ID_Acomp == pa.ID_Acomp &&
                       a.ID_Area_Acomp == 15 &&
                       a.SITUACAO_ACOMPANHAMENTOes.Any(b=>b.ST_Sit_Acomp.Equals("A"))                           
                 select a).ToList();
```